# Unable to retrieve extra headers - Mailcore

Tags: ios, swift, email, mailcore2, mailcore

For some emails i want to send extra data with headers. Like I want to know that an email is encrypted or not. For this purpose i am setting extra header like below.

**Setting extra header**

```
let mailBuilder: MCOMessageBuilder! =  MCOMessageBuilder()
mailBuilder.header.subject = "Subject"
mailBuilder.header.setExtraHeaderValue("yes", forName: "Encrypted")
// set rest of data.  From,TO,CC,Body etc and send email.. // Email sending is working properly.
```

**Retrieving extra header**

```
func fetchRequestKind () -> MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind {
        let kind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind()
        let headers = kind.union(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.headers)
        let structure = headers.union(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.structure)
        let request = structure.union(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.flags)
        let requestHeader = request.union(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.extraHeaders)
        return requestHeader
    }

 let request = self.fetchRequestKind()

                    let messagesNumbers = MCOIndexSet.init() // range get set here
                    let fetch : MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation = self.imapSession.fetchMessagesByNumberOperation(withFolder: "Inbox", requestKind:request, numbers: messagesNumbers)
                    fetch.start({ (error, fetchedMessages, vanishedMessages) in
                        if(error != nil)
                        {
                            failure(error.debugDescription)
                        } else {
                            if let mails = fetchedMessages as? [MCOIMAPMessage] {
                               print("\(mails[0].header.subject) &&& \(mails[0].header.allExtraHeadersNames())")
                        }
                    })
```

But i am not getting extra headers this way.. 
What i am doing wrong here.? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the extra header you want in the fetch operation before you start it. In your case:

```
fetch.extraHeaders = ["Encrypted"]
```

Then you can retrieve the value with:

```
mails[0].header.extraHeaderValue(forName: "Encrypted")
```

Reference: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/1288